# Converting a recursive code to reverse a string into an iterative one in c++

Tags: arrays, string, recursion, dynamic, iteration

[image: example ... I want the iterative code to work this way not the ordinary way]
this is my code included a recursive  code, and I wanna convert it to an iterative one but I want it to reverse the string exactky the way it does by recursion .. is it possible 
I mean by dividing it

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

string reverse (string temp, int length)
{
    if (length == 1)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        int t = (temp.length() + 1) / 2;
        return
            reverse(
                temp.substr(t, temp.length() - 1),
                t
            ) +
            reverse(
                temp.substr(0, t),
                t
            );
    }
}

int main() {
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    string rev = reverse(s, s.length());
    cout <<"\n"<<rev;
    cin>>s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't"? What problem are you running into? The code posted compiles and appears to reverse a typed-in string.

Comment: if I insert a " cout << temp ;  "  before the return in function reverse .. it's not going to show the subresults that are in the picture

Comment: The program works correctly with `hellokitty` as input (result : `yttikolleh`). You should precise what you expect as output. Do you want to see the steps? If yes, please [edit] your question and show us the **exact** output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The `non-recursive` version of code for reversing a `string` can be done by swapping every `i` position up to half with `len - i - 1`,  as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    // Itearative code for reversing string s
    int len = s.size();
    int leftIdx = 0, rightIdx = len - 1;
    while (leftIdx < rightIdx) {
        swap(s[leftIdx], s[rightIdx]); // swapping index (i) with (len - i - 1)
        leftIdx++, rightIdx--;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you please have a look to the example I've just added